# Running SQL query - getting timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timeout

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM URLForPosting WITH(nolock) 
WHERE status = 0 
ORDER BY newid()
```

This is the query when I run in code I get timeout, even when I run it at SQL Server I get timeout.

However when I do this

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM URLForPosting WITH(nolock) 
WHERE status = 0
```

It runs perfectly fine.

Also the first query was running fine until the records for the first 6 lacks records its has total 8 lack now it gives time out? I have created index on status.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The Order by newid() is a no-go. You sort by a value that is completely random and can't be indexed! What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am selecting links from the database and i want to get them randomly and when after completing my task i set there status to 1...

Comment: What do you suggest i do if i want to randomly pick values from the database not in a order

Comment: what do you mean by newid()? You should have column names in order by clause.

Comment: How many records in that table?

Comment: well new id is a default function like random now the ID ..table ...which is my primary key

Comment: @Pavan Reddy: newid() in order by randomizes the output. but is quite dangerous on tables with a lot of records...

Comment: or in other words newid() ...automatically selects id from the id table...

Comment: yes,so what you suggest i do?

Comment: There are 8 lack records,,,,it worked fine with newid() till 6lack ..

Answer (score 5):

An alternative way to return a random record is to use [`TABLESAMPLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108(v=SQL.100).aspx). See how this performs:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM URLForPosting TABLESAMPLE(1) WITH(nolock) 
WHERE status=0 
ORDER BY newid()
```

`TABLESAMPLE` is available in SQL Server 2005 and later versions.

Comment: +1 because I never knew about this, **but**: `If you specify a small number, such as 5, you might not receive results in the sample.`

Comment: well i used this instead of newid() and it solved the problem

SELECT top 1 * FROM URLForPosting
  WHERE status=0 and (ABS(CAST(
  (BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) *
  RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 1

Answer (score 0):

Since it was running fine for when you had 600K records and is hanging at 800K it is likely that the inserts have caused your indexes to become fragmented. Get your DBA (or someone with `db_owner` rights) to run `DBCC DBREINDEX(URLForPosting)`.

Or for versions 2005 upwards you can use [ALTER INDEX REBUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx).

Comment: well i used this instead of newid() and it solved the problem SELECT top 1 * FROM URLForPosting WHERE status=0 and (ABS(CAST( (BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) * RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 1